# Eigenvalues of a Kronecker Product type matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, multilinear-algebra, kronecker-product

We have matrix $C$ of the form:

$C =\begin{bmatrix} B_{1,1} A_{1,1} & B_{1,2} A_{1,2} & \dots &  B_{1,K} A_{1,K}  \\ B_{2,1} A_{2,1}  & B_{2,2} A_{2,2} & \dots & B_{2,K} A_{2,K}\\ & & \ddots &  \\ B_{K,1} A_{K,1} & B_{K,2} A_{K,2} & \dots &  B_{K,K} A_{K,K} \end{bmatrix}$

where $B_{i,j}$ is a scalar, and $A_{i,j}$ is a matrix.

We also know that $B$ is a Markov (transition) matrix (the matrix consisted of $B_{i,j}$) , and each block $A_{i,j}$ is also Markov matrix.

I can numerically verify that eigenvalues of the $B$ matrix will be contained within the eigenvalues of $C$. (Eigenvalues of $B$ are also eigenvalues of $C$.)  However, I can't mathematically prove this. Does anyone have any suggestion?

In the Kronecker product case $(C = B \otimes A)$, this is easy to see, since eigenvalues will be the outer product of the eigenvalues of the two matrices.

Comment: Since all $A_{ij}$ are stochastic then the vector with all coordinates equal to 1 is a common eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue 1. Let's'call this vector $u$. If $v$ is a eigenvector of $B$ associated to an eigenvalue $b$ then  $Cv\otimes u=bv\otimes u$.

Comment: But, no, all ones vector is not an eigenvector of the block Ai,j in general.

Comment: What is your definition of markov matrix? If  the row sums of $A_{ij}$ are all equal to 1 then the vector with all coordinates equal to 1 is an eigenvector. If the column sums are equal to 1 consider the transpose of $C$ and remind that the tranpose of $C$ has the same eigenvalues of $C$.

Comment: Thans a lot! I can see it now.